# Reading scroll offsets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div in this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/vLQrK/2/ - with content that overflows, and I have overflow:scroll set.  I'd like to be able to read how much of the content is outside of div#box when I click the Read Offset button. When the scroll bar is at the top I would expect to read 0  and when the scroll bar is at the bottom I would expect to read about 80. Clearly, what I have in the button handler now is not correct:

```
$('button#readOffset').click(function() {
       console.log("offset = " + $(window).scrollTop());
   });
```

Second, I'd like to guarantee that every time the page loads, the scroll bar starts at the top.  In the application this example came from, the position of the scroll bar is remembered from the last value the last time the page was in the browser, though in this jsfiddle it always starts at the top, like I want. I don't know what the difference is between the jsfiddle here and the full application, but if there's some code that will guarantee that the scroll is always initialized to the top I'd like to use it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Subtract the height of the div by its current scroll offset...

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't remember the last scroll position, because you haven't added code that can save and retrieve such information.  Your app apparently has that logic built in.  It probably uses either a server side programming language or a cookie to achieve this.

Comment: @jahroy: Some browsers (i think all but i only use Firefox on a regular enough basis to comment) will do that on their own at least as far as the overall window scroll position... not sure about DIV's

Comment: Here's [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jahroy/vLQrK/4/) you can play with.  I'm not sure wif that "_17 pixel fudge_" is correct or not...

Comment: @jahroy:  Thanks for putting the fiddle together. I think, though, all I need is $('box".scrollTop(). See my comment below to xuaxeuz's answer. Regarding the "memory" problem, I wrote every line of the application and I guarantee that no cookies or server-side code are involved. So I suspect that prodigitalson has the answer and it's being remembered by the browser.  Since the environment here is a DIV and not the overall window, I cast my vote for the window problem also affecting DIVs.

Comment: Ok... That's all good.  If you want to have the page start at the top, just put this in a document ready handler:  `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 });`  Or... do the same thing for your divs.

Comment: Wow... That's surprising that a browser would do that for you.  Sounds like a questionable feature to me... Although I guess it's never bothered me since I've never noticed it.  For the record, it doesn't appear that Opera 12.16 does this.  To be honest, I can't convince myself that any browser does this as I sit here and test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake. You are reading scrollTop() from window, you must to select the element have scroll $('#box') in this case.

```
$('#readOffset').click(function() {
   console.log("offset = " + $("#box").scrollTop());
});
```

Comment: Yes, I knew it was wrong, as I mentioned in my question.  I just didn't know, yet, what was correct.  What you've shown is, I believe, correct. The jQuery reference for .scrollTop() says it gives: "the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area." And that's what I want. We don't need to subtract the box height, etc.